# the structure of json string

Tags: php, json

expected json string is:

```
{
    "nodes": [
        {
            "node": {
                "field1": "Book1", 
                "field2": "Book2", 
                "field3": "Book3"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "node": {
                "field1": "Book1", 
                "field2": "Book2", 
                "field3": "Book3"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

this is my code stuff:

```
<?php

//Mysql stuff.
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('dbname');

//create a query string to use
$query = "SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM table";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$node['node']=$array;
$concat['node']=array($node);

echo json_encode($concat);

?>
```

it just returns first element of an array.

so, when I try with while loop as follow:

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
    $json[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode( $json );
```

it outputs like that:

```
[
    {
        "field1": "Book1", 
        "field2": "Book2",
        "field3": "Book3"
    }, 
    {
        "field1": "Book1", 
        "field2": "Book2",
        "field3": "Book3"
    }
]
```

I'm a newbie in json structure, how can I get expected json string? Any ideas?

Comment: put the output of: echo "<pre>"; print_r($concat); echo "</pre>";

Answer (score 1):

```
$json['nodes'] = Array();

 ...

$json['nodes'][] = Array('node' => $row);
```

Comment: `while( $array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {

 $json['nodes'][] = Array('node' => $array);
 
}
echo json_encode($json);`@Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams - I got expected json string :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$array = array
(
        'nodes' => array
        (
                array
                (
                        'node' => array
                        (
                                'field1' => 'Book1',
                                'field2' => 'Book2'
                        )
                ),
                array
                (
                        'node' => array
                        ( 
                                'field3' => 'Book3',
                                'field4' => 'Book4' 
                        )                       
                )

        )
);

echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

this php script outputs the structure that you need